# how to trace by carriage return in a string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i m facing small issue my xml which looks like this mentioned as bellow for this i m writting a logic in xslt but i cant able to reach output can any one help me please kindly asap
    here my XML

```
  <block4>  
    <tag>
    <name>72</name>
    <value>/BNF/
           FETA/ABNAAFU000000D93--16.560-10/</value>
  </tag>
  </block4>
```

here my XSL

```
<xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name = '72']">
<xsl:value-of  select="concat((concat(substring-before(value,'&#13;'),',')),(substring-after(value,'&#13;'))) "/>
</xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/>
```

output required:
**/BNF/,FETA/ABNAAFU000000D93--16.560-10/**

note : i am trying to get output as such **LINE1,LINE2**

Comment: Punctuation is recommended. If you want someone to make the effort to help you, make the effort to make it easier for them to understand your question.

Comment: P.S. when something is not working right, it's a good idea to tell what your *actual* output is (as well as what it *should* be, which you already described).

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I think a combination of the `normalize-space` and `translate` functions are what you want, something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name = '72']">
    <xsl:value-of  select="translate(normalize-space(value), ' ', ',')"/>
</xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/>
```

The `normalize-space` will turn all whitespace into spaces, and convert multiple spaces into a single space. The `translate` will turn all the remaining spaces into commas.